# Обновление Laravel 5.8 до Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, openserver

Проект у меня стоит на OpenServer 5.2.2. Версия php 7.1-х64.

Чтобы обновить проект на 6.0, сменил версию php на Openserver-е ПКМ->Настройки->Модули->PHP  на 7.3-х64 и перезапустил. Потом сделал все как в документации на официальном сайте https://laravel.com/docs/6.x. И composer установил по человечески. Но когда на терминале отправил запрос  composer update выходит такая ошибка:

```html
C:\OSPanel\domains\laravelu.loc>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v6.5.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.4.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.4.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.3.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.1.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.0.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.0.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.0.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v6.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework 6.x-dev requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0].
```

Будьте любезны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `your PHP version (7.1.22)` - вы не изменили версию PHP в вашем OpenServer.

Comment: Проверяйте пожалуйста. Добавил скриншот после перезапуска ОпенСервера.

Comment: Попробуйте проверить версию php непосредственно в терминале: php -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Измените версию Apache. У вас стоит 7.0-7.1
Что попросту не даст вам использовать выше 7.1 версию PHP.

Поставьте необходимую поддержку и попробуйте снова.

Answer (score 0):

OpenServer меняет версию php через который работает вебсервер. При выполнении композера из консоли он использует глобальную версию php установленную на сервере/компьютере. Я давно не пользовался Опенсервер но например в Мампе есть функция переопределения локальной версии. В противном случае надо обновить php на сервере/компьютере или использовать полный пусть до bin файла.